# Data hazards in a single instruction

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture, cpu-hazard

Considering the following mips code snippet

```
add $t1, $t1,$t2
lw $t1, 0($sp)
```

I understand that there is a WAW data hazard on `$t1` between instructions 1 and 2, but is there a WAR hazard on line 1 because we read from and write to `$t1` in a single instruction?

Comment: There's no RAW (true dependency) here.  `lw` *writes* `$t1`, not reads it.  It's actually a WAW and WAR on `$t1`, because `lw` writes `$t1` after `add` both reads and writes it.

Comment: You are correct, it was a typo and my bad. I have corrected it.

Comment: You're still missing the fact that there's a WAR hazard between 2 and 1, as well as WAW.  That's separate from your question about a WAR hazard *within* the `add` instruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We consider WAR hazard as a problem of out of order machine, due to executing instructions in other than program order.

Given the program

```
add $t4, $t1, $t5 ; instruction 1, program order
add $t5, $t1, $t2 ; instruction 2, program order
```

An out of order machine could decide to execute 1&2 in parallel, or even 2 first then 1, as there is no data dependency between them (no RAW).  This creates the opportunity for the WAR hazard — that if instruction 2 completes far earlier than instruction 1, without mitigation, instruction 1 would incorrectly see instruction 2's `$t5` value — let's note that this new value is a real program value for that register (just that it is not valid for prior instructions) so, this makes 2 different possible values for `$t5`.

---

> is there a WAR hazard on line 1 because we read from and write to $t1 in a single instruction?

No, within a single instruction, like `add $t1, $t1, $t2` the processor does not have a new value of `$t1` until it computes the result of the addition, for which it must have already sourced `$t1` and `$t2` — thus, there is no realistic possibility to confuse the new value with the old value (within an instruction) since the new value doesn't yet exist at the time of the addition.  There is no alternate ordering that will make the new value exist prior to the moment of the actual addition.